# How to fix error net::connection_refused in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created a small program for one site using attribute WebView, but after opening app I saw an error net::connection_refused.
How I can fix it?[How you can see on the bottom of image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA5Qc.png)

This is MainActivity file

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        final Activity activity = this;

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
                // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
                onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("https://black-minecraft.com/");

        setContentView(webView);
    }
}
```

Comment: is Internet permission given in your manifest file.

Comment: Of course. How you can see, i connected to the site